# Using a VBA userform in Excel 2011 on Mac (programmed in Windows): textbox doesn't work

Tags: macos, excel, vba, textbox

I've created a userform in Excel (in Windows, using VBA with no ActiveX controls) that includes several textboxes.  When the user enters a row number and presses a button, these textboxes are meant to display text from specific cells in that row.  This works fine in Windows, but when I try to use the userform on a Mac with Excel 2011, one of the textboxes doesn't properly display the text--instead, it becomes visible but is just blank.

The other textboxes on the form work fine, and the text that doesn't display was originally exported by Thunderbird and contains e-mail messages.  I know that I'm pulling in the right cell, because when I add "MsgBox(emailtext)" to my code, a message box pops up containing the text I want to display--it just won't show up in the textbox!  I'm wondering if this is some sort of character encoding problem.  I've defined the variable ("emailtext") as String and have then simply assigned it the value of the cell I want ("emailtext = Sheet2.Cells(rownumber, 7)").  As I said, this approach works just fine for the next column over, which contains text that was entered directly into excel and doesn't contain any weird characters.  Any thoughts on how to get this text to display?

Answer (score 0):

```
With Textbox1
    .Locked = False
    .Text = Sheet2.Cells(rowNum, 7).Text
    .Locked = True
End With
```

Text of locked UserForm TextBoxes cannot be set with VBA in Excel for Mac 2011.  This isn't true for all the other versions of Excel I've tested (Excel for PC 2007-2016 nor Excel for Mac 2016).  Strange!